# AFNetworking: Cache.db created but cache-control → no-cache in server response heder

Tags: ios, nsurlcache, afnetworking-3, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

In my iOS app I'm using `AFNetworking` library to send POST requests to the server. The server response headers contain `cache-control → no-cache`. In my custom `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass I don't explicitly set the `NSURLRequestCachePolicy`, so I think that the default `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` is used. Apple documentation for `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` says:

> Specifies that the caching logic defined in the protocol implementation, if any, is used for a particular URL load request. This is the default policy for URL load requests. This policy is described further in the discussion below.

In my case the caching logic is `cache-control → no-cache` so I don't understand why I have `Cache.db` stored in iOS simulator Library Caches folder of my app.

Anyone could help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

The cache database is probably created as soon as the OS sets the size of the on-disk cache.  Its existence does not imply that it is actually being used.